# Не работает свайп сцен, какова причина?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-3

Вот пример моего кода:

```
package  {

        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.GestureEvent;
        import flash.events.TransformGestureEvent;
        import flash.ui.Multitouch;
        import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
        import flash.system.TouchscreenType;

        public class swipe extends MovieClip { 
            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

            public function swipeEffect(event:TransformGestureEvent):void{
                if(event.offsetX == 1)
            {
                prevScene();
            }
            else if(event.offsetX == -1)
            {
                nextScene();
            }
                }
            }
    }
```

Это внутри каждой сцены:

```
stage.addEventListener (TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, swipeEffect);
```

Есть флэш-сцены, которые должны переключаться только при свайпе в право или влево, однако размещение в каждой сцене под разными названиями никакого эффекта не дает, так же свайпить не хочет и так. Уже все перепробовал, но свайп не работает ни в браузере при включенной консоли, ни на сенсорном мониторе. Помогите новичку разобраться, что не так с кодом.

Установка внутри сцены (нумерация функций разная и соответствует номеру сцены), без участия встроенного файла .as, тоже не дает результата:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
stage.addEventListener (TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, swipeEffect1);

function swipeEffect1(event:TransformGestureEvent):void{
                if(event.offsetX == 1)
            {
                prevScene();
            }
            else if(event.offsetX == -1)
            {
                nextScene();
            }
                }
```

Ошибок никаких не выдает, работает в строгом режиме

Comment: У stage вместо addListener вам нужен addEventListener. Называть имя метода по имени класса очень плохая идея, поскольку так именуются конструкторы. Ну и всегда можно локализовать проблему, добавив отладочные сообщений.

Comment: Изменил название функции, чтобы оно не совпадало с названием класса, внутри сцены также изменил. Свайп все равно не работает, но при этом также перестала работать автовоспроизведение анимации на сцене

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня хром блокирует flash player при переходе в режим тестирования под мобильные телефоны, а других вариантов проверить нету. Поэтому могу дать инструкцию по AIR для Android. В теории обработка события в AIR и обычном AS3 приложении не должна отличаться.

Создаем новое приложение AIR for Android и сохраняем в папку для проекта. Создаем MovieClip, который будем использовать, указав галочку "Экспорт в ActionScript". В моем случае это будет простой клип с пятью фреймами и простым текстом по номеру фрейма.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее в библиотеке выбираем наш MovieClip, нажимаем ПКМ->свойства и редактировать класс. После редактирования сохраняем его с проектом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.TransformGestureEvent;
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

    public class SwipeTest extends MovieClip {


        public function SwipeTest() {
            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;         

            this.root.stage.stopAllMovieClips();
            this.root.stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, swipe);
        }

        public function swipe(event){
            if(event.offsetX == 1)
            {
                trace("swipe prev");
                prevFrame();
            }
            else if(event.offsetX == -1)
            {
                trace("swipe next");
                nextFrame();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

По идее это все, что надо, чтобы приложение заработало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Лучше используйте фреймы у MovieClip как альтернативу сценам т.к. с главными сценами очень много всяких подводных камней, которые надо учитывать. А функционал у них по факту одинаковый.

Comment: Я уже днем решил проблему, ушло почти 4 дня на выявление причины. Переход по сценам работает видно только в среде AIR, в swf режим разработчика видимо на всех браузерах блокируется, потому не в одном браузере не хотело контачить. В режиме AIR в тестировщике на свайп сработала первая сцена, а оставшиеся уже подкорректировал с помощью removeEventListener. Награду все равно отдаю, потому что в интернете с AS3 вообще тяжко по информации в плане реализации жестов. А данная информация пригодится для новичков.

Comment: Свайпы у меня не работали по той причине, что в проге был косяк и после переустановки, все библиотеки программы нормально загрузились. В итоге сделал AIR Desktop. Сцены удобны мне лишь потому, что анимации до черта в данной работе и бегать по 30 минутному таймлайну тяжеловато, когда в Actions весит куча элеметов, а так хотя бы переходы между сегментами где надо разделил на сцены.